# How to get the script name in Groovy

Tags: groovy, command-line

How do I get the name of the script being executed in Groovy?

It is not a command line argument and hence the *args* array is not of any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the present script name as follows.

```
def scriptName = this.class.getName()
println "Script FQCN : " + scriptName
```

It will print out the name of the script (which is nothing but a Class) with its package name - **FQCN** (Fully Qualified Class Name).

If you want just the script name and NOT the package, you can use

```
println "Script Simple Name : " + this.class.getSimpleName()
```

Answer (score 4):

I do this for a lot of scripts in a support class, so itsraghz 's answer doesnt work for me.

If you use this.class or getClass() from a support class called by the script, you'll get the support class's name, not the script's name. To get the script's name every time I use:

```
// Get the executed script as a (java) File
File scriptFile = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path)

// This holds the file name like "myscript.groovy"
def scriptName = scriptFile.getName()

// strip the extension to get "myscript"
def withoutExt = scriptName.take(scriptName.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions are perfect if applied in the script itself. Sometimes it is needed to know script name from other files or classes called from the script.

E.g. the script `script1.groovy` calls `SomeClass`. This `SomeClass` also can find the name of the script. One-line solution is

```
StackTraceUtils.deepSanitize(new Exception()).getStackTrace().last().getFileName()
```

Look at the following example:

`script1.groovy:`

```
import SomeClass
def someInst = new SomeClass()
```

`SomeClass.groovy:`

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils
class SomeClass {
   String scriptName = StackTraceUtils.deepSanitize(new Exception()).getStackTrace().last().getFileName().replaceAll(/\.groovy/, '')
   println "My calling script is '$scriptName'"
}
```

`output:`

```
My calling script is 'script1'
```

Comment: Thank you Naeel Maqsudov for supplementing the solution.